# Error when running Zeppelin to connect Neo4j & Spark

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to run : https://github.com/conker84/zep-neo4j-gc2k18

The 1st paragraph **Add Neo4j-Spark-Connector dependency:**

```
%spark.dep
z.reset()
z.load("neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.2.1-M5")
```

but an error occurred as follow:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:352)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.dep.SparkDependencyContext.fetchArtifactWithDep(SparkDependencyContext.java:171)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.dep.SparkDependencyContext.fetch(SparkDependencyContext.java:121)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.DepInterpreter.interpret(DepInterpreter.java:247)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:633)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What should I do to correct the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at an outdated version of Zeppelin integration. Nowadays Zeppelin supports querying Neo4j out of the box with https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/neo4j.html.

You can check out how I have done it in my repo: https://github.com/tomasonjo/zeppelin-graph-algo